# Spring returning image as ResponseEntity<byte[]> - image corrupt

Tags: spring, image, base64

I am working on a spring 3.2.7 app and it sends signatures stored in the database as base64 string back to the users browser via a spring controller which outputs the byte array ResponseEntity.

The image is always corrupted and I havent worked on this part of the system as I double checked in svn and the controller has not been touched since the branch I am working on was created.

I am able to convert the base64 string to an image on my desktop and I am also able to the convert the byte array returned to browser into an image before spring steps in.

Below is my code, this was apparently working before so perhaps there is some config change that could cause this?

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/submissions/signature/{type}/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getSignature(@PathVariable String type, @PathVariable Integer id) throws Exception {
   ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   String base64 = ... gets from db

   byte[] bytes = Base64.decodeBase64(base64);

    BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
    ImageIO.write(bi, "png", baos);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setLastModified(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime());
    headers.setCacheControl("no-cache");
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG);
    headers.setContentLength(baos.toByteArray().length);

    //Image as base64 string is ok in converter
    System.out.println("BASE 64 IMAGE IS: " + base64);
    //This image is created ok on desktop
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\p\\Desktop\\test_signature.png");
    fos.write(bytes);
    fos.close();
    //This image is created ok on desktop
    FileOutputStream fos3 = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\p\\Desktop\\test_signature_baos.png");
    fos3.write(bytes);
    fos3.close();

    return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(baos.toByteArray(), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
   }
```

The image is being rendered in the browser like:

```
   <img id="userSignature" width="296" height="110" style="border:0px" src="/webapp/service/submissions/signature/user/${subid}" alt="User signature" />
```

I have not changed this class and I am told that it did work, I am able to create images from both byte arrays and they are ok and looks the same and I able to render the signature string ok for testing like:

```
  <IMG SRC="data:image/png;base64, <base_64_string>" ALT="">
```

has anyone experienced similar issues or know what could be causing this?

I have now tried sending an image from my file system already created as png and that also fails.

I have now noticed that CSV files do not download properly in the app and they stream in the same way:

```
       @RequestMapping(value = "/results/csv", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getResultsInCsvFormat() throws IOException {
```

Comment: Looking at your code, I'm not sure why you'd use `ImageIO` at all; you can directly send the `bytes` as a part of the response and omit `bi` and `baos` entirely, e.g. `return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(bytes ...)`

Comment: I actually didnt write it a colleague of mine who is now away for a few weeks did, it hasnt actually changed since I took the code from svn, which is why I am struggling to understand what I could have changed to cause it? Apparently the ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter is registered automatically as I have nothing in the config which sets up that bean.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have successfully returned file contents with the help of an `InputStream`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/submissions/signature/{type}/{id}", 
                method = RequestMethod.GET)
public HttpEntity getFile(HttpServletResponse response,
                          @PathVariable String type, 
                          @PathVariable Integer id) {
    String base64 = "foo"; // get base-64 encoded string from db
    byte[] bytes = Base64.decodeBase64(base64);
    try (InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)) {
        StreamUtils.copy(inputStream, response.getOutputStream());
        response.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // handle
    }
    return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Note that I'm not using `ResponseBody`, and in my working version I am using `MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE` rather than the actual file content type.

Comment: I just tried your example and it works and the images render ok so.... seeing as I havent changed anything in the controller that does image downloads and I havent changed anything in the controller that does csv downloads and this previously worked... what could now be causing the ResponseEntity download to fail?

Comment: Perhaps `ResponseEntity<byte[]>` is automatically base-64 encoded?

Comment: @berimbolo Ah, the answer is probably `ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter`; what happens if you just remove `@ResponseBody`?

Comment: Any idea why this would have just started happening and what I need to do to resolve the issue?

Comment: @berimbolo Perhaps it's a change in the default spring behavior or which message converters are included by default? What happens when you just remove `@ResponseBody` from your original method?

Comment: That didnt make a difference when I removed the @ResponseBody tag

Answer (score 1):

The accepted solution didn't work for me in Spring Boot 2.x for Base64 images. Here is how I returned a Base64 image:

```java
@GetMapping(value = "/pixels/{id}", produces = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public byte[] pixelTracking(@PathVariable String id) {

    // TODO: do whatever you want here

    // return png image
    String base64 = "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mP8/x8AAwMCAO+ip1sAAAAASUVORK5CYII=";
    return Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I have fixed this now with some thanks to beerbajay who showed me that downloading by streaming to the response directly was ok and also that I should look at ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter.

It turned out that I had made a mistake in the spring config and I realised this after reading the spring documentation that told me that ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter is registered automatically when using      <mvc:annotation-driven />.

The mvc annotation driven tag had been removed from the config as I thought this was doing the same thing (and I thought it only needed to be declared once within a spring context):

```
   <mvc:annotation-driven content-negotiation-manager="contentNegotiationManager">
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter" />
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

It looks like this alone isnt sufficient to set up annotation-driven in the app and I have added back in the  tag to the context.xml file.

I dont understand why this needs to be in two places though as all the xml config is loaded through same xml file in what I assumed was the same spring context:

```
<import resource="config/properties.xml" />

<import resource="config/security.xml" />

<import resource="config/context.xml" />

<import resource="config/content-negotiation.xml" />

<import resource="config/rest-client.xml" />
```

Comment: I have since completely removed the content-negotiation.xml file which was setting up jackson content negotiation for no reason as its already done it seems by the annotation-config call in context.xml. So it looks like I was just backwards when I removed the annotation-config the only content type aside from tiles content the app could deal with was json.

Answer (score 0):

my solution is :

backend is spring boot and frontend is reactjs

bug is different syntax is backend and frontend : java use ("_","-") and web(reactjs,...) use ("/","+")  |
for example :  "PGjQOA66-_*ne*-" convert to "PGjQOA66+//ne/+"

you can testing base64 in this link :https://onlinepngtools.com/convert-base64-to-png

back end code :

```
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        File file = new File(path);/// path : is external directory and local directory in server
        FileInputStream imageInFile = new FileInputStream(path);
        byte imageData[] = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        imageInFile.read(imageData);
        String base64 =  encodeImage(imageData);
        /// 1. Not show if size up  300KB !!! :|
        /// 2. base64.replaceAll("_","/").replaceAll("-","+") 
        byte[] bytes = Base64.decodeBase64(base64.replaceAll("_","/").replaceAll("-","+"));
        BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
        ImageIO.write(bi, "png", baos);


        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setLastModified(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime());
        headers.setCacheControl("no-cache");
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG);
        headers.setContentLength(baos.toByteArray().length);
        return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(baos.toByteArray(), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
```

and other solution for back end:

```
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        File file = new File(path);/// path : is external directory file and local directory file in server, or path get of database.
        FileInputStream imageInFile = new FileInputStream(path);
        byte imageData[] = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        imageInFile.read(imageData);
        /// 1. Not show if size up  300KB !!! :| i dont now!
        /// 2. base64.replaceAll("_","/").replaceAll("-","+") 
        String base64 =  encodeImage(imageData).replaceAll("_","/").replaceAll("-","+");
        return base64;
```

and reactjs code is :

```
    const [imageData, setImageData] = React.useState({});
        
    setImageData(...request to backend);
    <img  src={`data:image/png;base64,${imageData}`} alt="This Is alert" />
```